# auto refresh markers every x seconds in php and js

Tags: javascript

hello i am trying to auto refresh markers on the page who display google map.
i searched for many hours and cant find a good solution for my example.

please if someone has a good way for me ?

i tried many methods but i cant have the result i want.

...

```
var map;
var geocoder;
function loadMap() {
    var pune = {lat: 18.5204, lng: 73.8567};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: pune
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pune,
    map: map
    });

    var cdata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
    codeAddress(cdata);

    var allData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('allData').innerHTML);
    showAllColleges(allData)
}

function showAllColleges(allData) {
    var infoWind = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(allData, function(data){
        var content = document.createElement('div');
        var strong = document.createElement('strong');
    
        strong.textContent = data.name;
        content.appendChild(strong);

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'img/Leopard.jpg';
        img.style.width = '100px';
        content.appendChild(img);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
        map: map
    });

        marker.addListener('mouseover', function(){
        infoWind.setContent(content);
        infoWind.open(map, marker);
    })
    
        marker.addListener('mouseup', function(){
        infoWind.close(map, marker);
    })
    })
  }

 function codeAddress(cdata) {
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(cdata, function(data){
    var address = data.name + ' ' + data.address;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var points = {};
        points.id = data.id;
        points.lat = map.getCenter().lat();
        points.lng = map.getCenter().lng();
        updateCollegeWithLatLng(points);
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
});
}
```

(here i set an interval :)

```
  setInterval(function updateCollegeWithLatLng(points) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"action.php",
        method:"post",
        data: points,
        success: function(res) {
        console.log(res)
    }
})

}, 3000)
```

the console message

**Notice**:  Undefined index: id in **/storage/ssd3/702/16987702/public_html/google-map-php-mysql-master/action.php** on line **4**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: lat in **/storage/ssd3/702/16987702/public_html/google-map-php-mysql-master/action.php** on line **5**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: lng in **/storage/ssd3/702/16987702/public_html/google-map-php-mysql-master/action.php** on line **6**
Updated...

Comment: I have to wonder why you need to update the map. Do these colleges move far in 3 seconds? Classes must be an interesting experience!

Comment: ah ah its an example that i follow on youtube; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y60X-bAdavg

Comment: i am able to return the datatable sql...now i must reencode into markers coords...